# Writing a sentence that is true in one model and false in the other

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic

> Let $Σ=(R)$, where $R$ is a binary relation. Write a sentence that is true in $\mathcal M_1$ but false in $\mathcal M_2$:
>
> $$\mathcal M_1=(P(N),⊂)$$
>
> $$\mathcal M_2=(N,<)$$

I've been trying to find this sentence for a couple of hours now and they just seem too equivalent, every sentence that i find is either good for both of them or bad for both of them,

Thanks in advance !

Comment: In usual terminology, a sentence is true in a model, not "for a dictionary". Edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: There is nothing in $M_2$ corresponding to the relationship between the subsets $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$ of $\Bbb N$ in $M_1$. Your sentence should start $\exists x\,\exists y\ldots$.